# Java IntelliJ : system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently I upgraded my windows and when I opened IntelliJ (IDE for JAVA) to code it shows the following error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Lenovo\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.3\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have installed jdk and intelliJ into disk E. Kindly guide me how to fix it.

Comment: Apparently "C:\Users\Lenovo\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" does not exist. It says it in the error.

Comment: @Dropout because it is in disk E not C

Comment: Have you tried changing your SDK in IDEA so it points to the correct executable?

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Project